# Missing data for column SQL COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE data 
(
    event_time  DATE,
    event_type1 TEXT,
    event_type2 TEXT,
    event_type3 TEXT,
    event_type4 TEXT,
    continent   TEXT
);

COPY data
FROM '/home/data/data.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ';' ;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: missing data for column "event_type3"
> Where: COPY dilans_data, line 11: "2018-01-01 00:07:41;subscribe;2458151268"
> 1 statement failed.

I do have missing values in some columns but first I would like to import the data after dealing with it.

I tried to add: NULL 'null_string' (NaN, N, 0) but it did not worked.

Can you help me?

Comment: 1) The `NULL` string is `\N` in `text` format and unquoted empty string in `csv` per [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) 2) Because of 1) your row needs to be `2018-01-01 00:07:41;subscribe;2458151268;;;`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table with the columns for which you have data and then add the other columns after the import.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE data 
> (
>     event_time  DATE,
>     event_type1 TEXT,
>     event_type2 TEXT
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into data values ('2018-01-01 00:07:41','subscribe','2458151268');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN  event_type3 TEXT;
> ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN  event_type4 TEXT ;
> ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN  continent TEXT ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM data;
> ```
>
> ```
> event_time | event_type1 | event_type2 | event_type3 | event_type4 | continent
> :--------- | :---------- | :---------- | :---------- | :---------- | :--------
> 2018-01-01 | subscribe   | 2458151268  | null        | null        | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8c46196fe58245e01b6639ba01086c97)*

Comment: Got the same error message.

Comment: I don't see how you can have got an error message with event_type3 if it isn't in the table before the import. please give the new error message